# I can't change the app-release.apk file name of the flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

### Configured as Android native

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The file has been generated, But I got:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     140.0s (!)
Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under E:\enzo\code\flutter\yd_xuantao\build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

And `flutter run` gets the same error

### Try to set archivesBaseName

```
defaultConfig {
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "driver-v" + flutterVersionName)
}
```

It's still that error

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      53.1s
Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under E:\enzo\code\flutter\yd_xuantao\build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.329], locale zh-CN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] VS Code (version 1.46.0)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: can you run 'flutter doctor' and paste the code to your question?